# Ubuntu Wiki refuses to change theme

Tags: ubuntu-wiki, ubuntu-website

I'm attempting to do everything I can in terms of trying to make sure my team's wiki page looks good, but sadly, I cannot seem to activate the new theme (I'm stuck using the old one, for some odd reason)

I get the message:

This email already belongs to somebody else.

Whenever I try and change theme (or other settings) How do I correct this?

Comment: Interesting; I have the same problem. This may be a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that's a bug

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-website/+bug/685436